# Why Babel.js transform generator into non-sequential switch case?

Tags: javascript, generator, code-generation, babeljs

I happens to view code generated by babel.js. The original source code is like this:

```
function * foo() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
```

The generated ES5 code is like:

```
"use strict";

var _marked = [foo].map(regeneratorRuntime.mark);

function foo() {
  return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function foo$(_context) {
    while (1) {
      switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
        case 0:
          _context.next = 2;
          return 1;

        case 2:
          _context.next = 4;
          return 2;

        case 4:
          _context.next = 6;
          return 3;

        case 6:
        case "end":
          return _context.stop();
      }
    }
  }, _marked[0], this);
}
```

My question is: why the generated case value is 0, 2, 4 and 6 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3?

Is there any reasoning behind this design?

Comment: I guess to answer this question you should just read the source.

Comment: The source code is here https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-regenerator , but frankly it is hard to get the meaning of it.

Answer (score 3):

> why the generated case value is 0, 2, 4 and 6 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3?

The case values don't really matter, they're not serially numbered because some of them were omitted. The code is generated [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-regenerator/src/emit.js#L230-L235), where cases are only inserted in the listing when they are marked. What that means is [even commented](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-regenerator/src/emit.js#L36-L38):

```
// A sparse array whose keys correspond to locations in this.listing
// that have been marked as branch/jump targets.
this.marked = [true];
```

The listing is just a list of statements - in fact very much the statements you're seeing in the output. For the particular code in your question, every time a [`yield` expression is encountered](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-regenerator/src/emit.js#L1153), it [does emit](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-regenerator/src/emit.js#L1173-L1175) an assignment to `context.next` and the actual return statement with the yielded value, and marks the next statement as a jump target. This is where your numbers are coming from. If you add some lines, they'll change.