# Why does Babel generate a switch statement with an assignment in the condition?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, babeljs

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652253/why-babel-js-transform-generator-into-non-sequential-switch-case), didn't answer this though.

Got some code generated in a React callback:

```
    return _babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.async(function _callee2$(_context3) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context3.prev = _context3.next) { // <<<<<----- this
          case 0:
            if (!(fileState.generationComplete || fileState.error || !fileState.generationInProgress)) {
              _context3.next = 2;
              break;
            }
```

I just can't see any advantage to putting an assignment in a switch: `switch (_context3.prev = _context3.next)`. I get that you'd want to set the prev to the next at the beginning of a loop but why do that in a `switch`?

Never seen this discussed before and it just seems odd to me.

Comment: Because it's shorter?

Comment: I guess it could also prevent potential bugs if `.prev` is a getter with side effects, but I am just guessing.

Comment: Transpiler output is not about readable or pretty code, it's about correct, efficient and short code.

Comment: "*I just can't see any advantage*" - can you see a disadvantage? What would you have used instead?